# The run test illustration graph intuition.

Tags: statistics

I was studying run test at https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/21/21.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

So there are 3 sketches here. I wonder how are x and y on the x-axis is related to the function. To me it seems that the observation depends on variance. Lower variance gets marked on x-axis over another group of observation.
For the first picture it seems that because the function are same they have xyxyxyxy.
For the second one it seems that F(z) has larger variance than G(z) and G(z) is only defined for positive values so the graph has xxxxyyyy. And same method of thinking goes on. But I doubt I am right.
Does the x and y depend on the variance? How is function and the mark(or say observation) x and y  related?